# HTML/CSS/SVG: SVG background image in IE7/8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, svg, background-image

I have made an svg image that I am using as a background image. I does not work in IE8 and below (as expected), and I thought I could use something use like: http://twostepmedia.co.uk/svgeezy/ or http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/. However, none of these support SVG as a background-image/background, only IMG and Object etc.

Code:

```
background:url('img/bck_hero.svg');
```

How can I get an SVG as the background in IE8/7 or have a fallback image? Is there a javascript library that could do this?

Thanks a lot,

Harley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to detect support for svg with javascript and then style differently depending on that.

If you use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) you could do it like this in your stylesheet:

```
#myElm.svg { background:url('img/bck_hero.svg'); }
#myElm.no-svg { background:url('img/bck_hero.png'); }
```

Comment: Please Read my question- **Svgeezy doesn't work**. Thanks for the Modernizr bit though!