# SVG to image on a client side for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg

I have a collection of svg files which are going to be used on my site. There is no any problem in modern browsers with showing SVG but we have if we're talking about IE. Is there any way to make IE shows SVG picture? Maybe some jquery/js plugin could do that?

```
<img src="images/icon.svg" width="32" height="32" alt="" />
```

I spent a lot of time and still havent found any workarounds :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make SVG work with IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427051/how-to-make-svg-work-with-ie)

Comment: Yes, I saw this topic but no answer there on my question. Raphael can't transform svg to image. As well as svgweb as far as I can see.

Comment: Some more related/possible-duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262973/html-css-svg-svg-background-image-in-ie7-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118254/reliably-detecting-img-tag-support-for-svg

Comment: No. Not dublicated. I can't use png instead as fallback. I want to convert svg to png(jpg, gif whatever image format)

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Could you please update the question with your reasons for not being able to use a pre-generated raster image and why you must you <img> specifically, instead of eg. <object>?

Comment: 1. We can't pregenerate png because there too many svg files and their amount can be increased. It's hard to make separated png file each time.
2. Yes, we can use "object" instead of "img" but IE doesn't work with as well. For example: http://htmltricks.ru/prj/svg2img

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19641/discussion-between-eugene-kuzmin-and-erik-dahlstrom)